# how to use selenium python to open new chat whatsapp (i need to target the second icon New Chat)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: i need to target the second icon New Chat]
[image: i need to target the second icon New Chat]

**I need to target the second icon New Chat but they have the same class name**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/ka-my/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')
user1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_3j8Pd')
user1.click()
```

1.i need to target the second icon New Chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just like Facebook and google the class names are dynamically generated So the best way around that is to look for something constant which is the icon string

```
new_chat = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@title="New chat"]') # return a list
if new_chat:
    new_chat[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get 2nd icon in new chat, you can use this:

```
# get the 2nd element in the list
second_icon = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3j8Pd']")[1]
```

Or:

```
# get the 2nd element in the list
second_icon = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_3j8Pd'][2]")
```

In first example, we are getting a list of all the `div` elements, and picking the 2nd item using the `[1]` index. In second example, we are using element index in XPath `[2]` to get the second element in the list. List index is 0-based and XPath element index is 1-based, so that is why we see 1 and 2 here.